# CakePHP validation form field

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp (v3.0). I have got a field "num_max_intents" that I want that only takes values greater than 0 and also I want that "date" field be greater than actual date.. 
My validationDefault() code is the next:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
    $validator->notEmpty('num_max_intents')
              ->notEmpty('package')
              ->notEmpty('date');
    return $validator;
}
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple solution, use a `range` validator:

```
$validator->add(
    'num_max_intents', 
    'valid', 
    ['rule' => ['range', 0, PHP_INT_MAX]]
);
```

This validator requires both the lower and upper limit to be set, so you have to use some value here. You can find all validators in `Cake\Validation\Validation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure as a custom validation rule. Just remember to return `true` if the rule validates and `false` if it fails. For example, to check the date field is greater than the current date:-

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
    $validator
        ->add('date', 'valid', ['rule' => function ($value) {
            return $value > date('Y-m-d');
        }]);
    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate "date" field I'm using this code:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
    $validator->add('date', 
                    'valid', [
                        'rule' => function ($value) {
                            return $value > date('Y-m-d'); },
                        'message' => 'Invalid date.'
                    ]
              )
              ->notEmpty('date');
    return $validator;
}
```

But when I select a date less than actual date on my form, the validator doesn't run correctly and doesn't show the error message... What's wrong?